# mysql insert record if something > something else

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `user`
    (`fname`,
    `lname`,
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `permission`,
    `idcustomer`)
         VALUES
    (
    '" . $firstname . "',
    '" . $lastname . "',
    '" . $email . "',            
    '" . $password . "',
    'admin',
    " . $idcustomer . "
    );";
```

Now, I need to execte this query only is the result of the query below is > 0:

```
select (number_of_users - (select count(*) from user where idcustomer=2)) availableUsers 
   from customer where idcustomer=2
```

Comment: I would use a simple if statement. E.g. if result = 0, then call function that executes the top SQL statement. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: I cann't understand your question??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `select` instead of `values(...)`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `user`
    (`fname`,
    `lname`,
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `permission`,
    `idcustomer`)
     select
    '" . $firstname . "',
    '" . $lastname . "',
    '" . $email . "',            
    '" . $password . "',
    'admin',
    " . $idcustomer . "
    from customer
    where idcustomer = 2
          and (number_of_users - (select count(*) from user where idcustomer=2)) > 0
    );";
```